# getelementbyid innerHTML to bbcode?

Tags: javascript

Anyway to convert `innerHTML` to `bbcode`?

Something like that

```
document.getelementbyid.('div').bbcode
```

or a way to replace `%0A` to `[br]` in the current link of the page?

I've tried this with no luck

```
window.location.replace('%0A', '[br]');
```

Answer (score 0):

.bbcode is not a valid function (or property how you've written it), unless of course you are including some kind of external library that you haven't told us about?

With regards to the window.location.replace you are not assigning it to anything so where would you expect to see the change? Though you should also use

```
 window.location.href.replace(needle,haystack);
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/9LGRP/1/ for a quick example or replace working to replace the word "show" with "foo"

Please note the syntax is slightly different for global replacements e.g

```
            window.location.href.replace(/foo/g, 'bar')
```

would replace all instances of foo. You can also add the modifier 'i' after the 'g' to    ignore case  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Perhaps you need to elaborate more on your question and show more context if this doesn't address your needs.